# resolv.conf custom nameserver using dhclient.conf gets removed on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

According to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns
I have added this at the end of `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` in order to have a custom nameserver on resolv.conf

```
prepend domain-name-servers x.x.x.x;
```

After a `service networking restart` resolv.conf file gets populated with the custom nameserver.

The problem is that after a few hours (around 12), sometimes more (I can't find exactly the time it takes) **the dhcp lease removes the nameserver from resolv.conf**

This is the syslog output at the moment that happens:

```
normal syslog output
...
dhclient[30756]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.207.0.40 on eth1 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
dhclient[30756]: DHCPACK of 10.207.0.40 from 169.254.169.254
liblogging-stdlog:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="11655" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
systemd[1]: Stopping System Logging Service...
systemd[1]: Stopped System Logging Service.
systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
dhclient[30756]: bound to 10.207.0.40 -- renewal in 35134 seconds.
liblogging-stdlog:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="26725" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
...
normal syslog output
```

I don't know why syslog stops and starts again...

Any ideas about what is writing the resolv.conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the file resolv.conf is being overwritten again and again is because DHCP lease expires on your instance. On documentation [1] says:

> Manually editing resolv.conf will result in it being reverted to the
>   default DHCP every time the 24-hour DHCP lease expires on your
>   instance. On instances using zonal DNS, the DHCP lease expires every
>   hour. To make static modifications in the resolv.conf file, several
>   Linux distributions allow items to be prepended or appended to the
>   DHCP policy.

That 24 hours lease is not an SLO so that could happen sooner than that.

Since you are in a Cloud environment, you can achieve the same behavior of editing the `resolv.conf` by making some configurations on Cloud DNS:

A) If you want to override the DNS to use an ON PREM DNS, you can create a “DNS server Policy” [2] [3] [4]

B) If you want to use your own bind (inside your Project) to create internal zones, you can use Cloud DNS private zones [5]

In cloud environments is never a good idea to override `resolv.conf`.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns-server-policy

[3] https://medium.com/fourcast-premier-google-cloud-partner/google-cloud-platform-dns-forwarding-is-a-big-thing-for-enterprises-305df0c6cf73

[4] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/best-practices-dns#best_practices_for_private_zones

[5] https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/#creating_private_zones

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
The goal is to have 3 URLs to be resolved using a DNS server over a VPN. Setting a dns policy needs work on the other side of the VPN (which I do not have control) to allow and route dns requests back to google cloud.
Yet I'll evaluate that option since it seems to be the most reliable one.
Thank you!